# Why does "npm install" require Node.js preinstalled in the system?

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css

I've recently started Tailwind CSS where I've to install Tailwind into my system, not knowing the fact that my system has to contain Node.js preinstalled in my system I proceeded to paste `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer` in the terminal but it threw so many errors. After some research, I found about Node.js. Though my problem is solved I want to know why it happened.

Comment: npm (node package manager) is itself written in javascript and is ran using node. so obviously you need node to run npm. npm also comes bundled with node if you properly install it yourself using either your preferred package manager or the installation files from https://nodejs.org

Answer (score 2):

The reason it needs nodejs is as simple as, you need to have a nodejs to have/use the npm. Nothing more than that.

Diving into what you are doing here: By running `npm install tailwind`, you are installing a node package called `tailwind` with a package management tool called `npm`. `Nodejs` is the javascript environment that gonna execute it later when you use it

Think of the the relationshipi between `pip` and `python`. When you try to install a python package, you use a python package manager called `pip`. What you are doing here is, you need tailwind css module, now you need node package manager (NPM) to have it download and work with nodejs.

Some furthur reading:

what is npm:
https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_npm.asp

Where your tailwind package come from:
https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm